# C++ alternative for C function-like macros

Tags: c++, callback, c-preprocessor

I have a demo C application that is using quite a lot preprocessor macros. I'm writing a similar application in 
C++ and don't know the suitable alternative for function macros like

```
#define CALL_PROTO_FUNC(_FUNCTION_, _ARGUMENTS_) \
```

Here is code snippet

```
#define PROTO_FUNC_SUCCESS                0x00   
#define PROTO_FUNC_ERR_NOT_SUPPORTED      0x01   
#define PROTO_FUNC_ERR_DATA_NOT_UPDATED   0x02   
#define PROTO_FUNC_ERR_NO_RESPONSE        0x03   

#define CALL_PROTO_FUNC(_FUNCTION_, _ARGUMENTS_) \
(ApplMgmt._FUNCTION_ != NULL) ? (ApplMgmt._FUNCTION_)_ARGUMENTS_ : (PROTO_FUNC_ERR_NOT_SUPPORTED)
```

How can CALL_PROTO_FUNC be implemented in C++, so that it is easier to debug in case of error.
I have made CALL_PROTO_FUNC inline function, but was wondering that if there is any other better way to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: alternative for macroses is a templates

Comment: If I interpreted the code correctly without studying it, I would think that in this case polymorphism is the C++ alternative.  I'm not sure enough to actually answer.

Comment: Read about the [Strategy design pattern](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Code/Design_Patterns#Strategy). You write an abstract base class defining the interface of your backends. Then, for each backend, write a subclass (inheriting from the abstract base class), overriding the functions from the interface (their implementation then equals your C functions `pfn_get_init_data` etc.) - The base class can also implement the functions (default implementation) with throwing an exception, reporting that the backend doesn't support this function.

Comment: @leemes, yes this looks like a way to go.